# Securing your APIs using Azure Active Directory SSO

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

How to secure your APIs using Azure Active Directory SSO Implementation using SAML 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

You can **[Protect an API in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)**

Hope this help!

Comment: can be used in conjunction with an app registration and app roles to protect an API behind APIM

Comment: I'm looking for SAML 2.0 Integration for protecting API's